# scoverage fails due to unresolved dependency path

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea, sbt, scoverage

**IDE_version:**

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2021.2.3

**Scala_version:**

- 3.1.0

**build.properties:**

- sbt.version=1.5.5

**libraryDependencies:**

- libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.10"
- libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.10" % "test"

**plugins:**

- addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.9.2")
- addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-coveralls" % "1.3.1")

**CI/CD:**

- Travis CI
- Coveralls.io

When I use the following commands inside the sbt shell `sbt clean test` everything just works fine.
As soon as I activate `coverage` before `test` and try to run the tests trough sbt I get following output.

```
[IJ]coverage
[info] Defining ThisBuild / coverageEnabled
[info] The new value will be used by Compile / compile / scalacOptions, libraryDependencies
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to my-project (in build file:/D:/Projects/my-project/)
[IJ]test
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_3:1.4.10
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\USER\.ivy2\localorg.scoverage\scalac-scoverage-runtime_3\1.4.10\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-runtime_3/1.4.10/scalac-scoverage-runtime_3-1.4.10.pom
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 04.11.2021, 16:23:17
```

I already tried downgrading all versions of the visible plugins and dependencies to avoid the problem. Nothing really changed.

For me it seems like as I activate coverage sbt tries to reference a library which is not reachable. In this case it would for what ever reason be the pom file of `scalac-scoverage-runtime_3\1.4.10\` that doesn't exist yet.

Has anyone an idea on that problem?

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

I received an answer by the devs of scoverage and they told me that at this time scoverage is not compatible yet with Scala 3. You can track the progress on https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/issues/299